# Telerik radlistbox datakey does not transfer

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radlistbox

I have two Telerik radListBoxes (source and destination). Both are databound with their DataKeyField and DataTextField values set. The destination listbox may have some values in it from a prior session.

When I transfer an item from the source listbox to the destination listbox using the built in buttons, I can see the value (text) is transferred over, but the datakey for that item is null.

I'm new to these controls, and everything is working well, except for this.

```
<telerik:RadListBox runat="server" ID="rlAvailableTitles" Height="200px" Width="300px" ButtonSettings-AreaWidth="35px" 
    AllowTransfer="true" TransferToID="rlTitles" SelectionMode="Multiple" AppendDataBoundItems="true"
    AllowTransferOnDoubleClick="true" DataKeyField="TitleID" DataTextField="TitleName" CssClass="text-align: left;" AutoPostBackOnTransfer="true">
</telerik:RadListBox>
<telerik:RadListBox runat="server" ID="rlTitles" Height="200px" Width="300px" ButtonSettings-AreaWidth="35px"
    AllowTransfer="true" TransferToID="rlAvailableTitles" SelectionMode="Multiple" AppendDataBoundItems="true"
    AllowTransferOnDoubleClick="true" DataKeyField="TitleID" DataTextField="TitleName">
</telerik:RadListBox>
```

And after they click on 'save':

```
foreach (RadListBoxItem item in rlTitles.Items)
{
    string myTitleID = item.DataKey;
    // etc...
}
```

What am I missing to get the datakey that is stored with the item in the source listbox?

Comment: What is your question? Be more specific.

Comment: would sure be nice to see the code you are using to help others understand your deficiency ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataKey has no setter.

Use DataValueField instead.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to this particular problem. I added `DataValueField="TitleID"` to the source radListBox in the aspx file. Then in my code behind, the value that I'm looking for in the destination radListBox is available in `item.Value`.  Seems pretty straight forward in retrospect.